# How to prove this is a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

A set $X=\lbrace x\in l^2:\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_k|^2<\infty\rbrace$. We need to prove that $\|x\|_X=\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_k|^2$ is a norm on set X. I tried to prove this through the four properties of the norm. But I have some difficulties of prove N3($\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha| \|x\|$) and N4($\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|$).

In N3, I prove $\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|^2\|x\|$, which is wrong. But I don't know how to prove it.

In N4, I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Minkowski inequality. But I'm stuck.

Could anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a norm. You have to modify the defnition as $\|x\|_X=\sqrt {\sum_{k \geq 1} k^{2}|x_k|^{2}}$.

Comment: Your computation for $N3$ is not wrong, as written. May be you gave the formula for $\|x\|_X^2$ instead ?

Comment: Just consider the sequence $y_k = k x_k$ then apply your standard knowledge.